# PHP Move Uploaded File Works on Localhost but Not on Server

Tags: php

The codes run smoothly locally but do not work when I send them to hosting.
I gave the folder permissions as 777, but I still couldn't solve it.
It gives 6 as an error code. This code means that there is no temporary folder, so I created another folder called temp on the hosting, but it is still not solved.
Can someone help me?

Here the application gives an error and gives the error "An error occurred while uploading the image"

```php
!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $imagePath)
```

All Codes

```php
  $targetFolder = 'uploads/';
  $imagePath = '';

  if (!empty($_FILES["img"]["name"])) {
      $imageName = uniqid() . '_' . $_FILES["img"]["name"];
      $imagePath = $targetFolder . $imageName;

      if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $imagePath)) {
          $response = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'An error occurred while uploading the image: ' . $_FILES["img"]["error"]
          );
          header('Content-Type: application/json');
          echo json_encode($response);
          exit; // Terminate the process if the image fails to upload
      }
  }
```

I'm just learning programming and I don't know much. I don't have a php.ini file on my server, could that be why I'm getting errors?

all code is running on my localhost. I use wampserver to run on localhost.

But when I upload it to hosting, the codes I specified do not work

I have almost all my folders set to 777 permissions.

The location to move the file is correct and there is no error.

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see the reason for the error.

Comment: when I checked 
PHP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/falbudur/public_html/admin/api.php on line 6

Line 6;

$temp= 'uploads/';
if (!is_dir($temp)) {
    mkdir($temp, 775, true);
}

ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', $temp);

Comment: There's no `mkdir()` call in the code you posted. That error is coming from another part of the script.

Comment: Try using an absolute path for `$temp`. The current directory isn't what you expect and it's not one that you gave `777` permission to.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$targetFolder` into this:

```
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads/';
```

Please note that is not good practice to upload files into the web accessible folders (e.g. /public_html/).
Most hosting providers have something like ~/private/.
Also check your phpinfo() / php.ini for open_basedir.

Please read [How to securely upload files with PHP?](https://docs.php.earth/security/uploading/)

Disclaimer: I'm in no way involved with PHP.earth; this page is a very nice sum-up of all the potential pitfalls you could encounter when dealing with uploads in PHP.